# Pass BackgroundWorker to class called by doWork?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, backgroundworker

Is this possible?

What I want to do is have my doWork method instantiate another class and then call its start method. Then i would like to report progress from that class back to the ProgressChanged handler in the parent class. I've tried passing a reference to the BackgroundWorker but i get an error.

```
private void ComplianceWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        ComplianceControlCenter CCC = 
         new ComplianceControlCenter(taskList.CheckedItems.OfType<string>().ToList(),
                                     file_box.Text, &ComplianceWorker);
        CCC.start();
    }
```

EDIT:

There is only 1 background worker. I would like to pass it by reference to the constructor of ComplianceControlCenter so i can send progress updates to it from inside that class. The reasoning is the class do some fairly complicated work and i need to have a division. So again, i would like to pass the background worker from the doWork method to the CCC object so i can call `ComplianceWorker.ReportProgress();`

> Error  1   Cannot take the address of, get the size of, or declare a pointer to a managed type ('System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker')

Comment: Then post the error details. I guess it has to do with the `&` in  `&ComplianceWorker` but I'd like to know for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do that, although I don't see what purpose it would serve for simple cases. Since you are *already* inside the business method of a `BackgroundWorker` there's no point in using yet more threads by creating another `BackgroundWorker` and you could do the same work inline.

If you still want to have a second `BackgroundWorker`, you can propagate progress changed events from the second worker to the first by attaching a handler to the second worker's `ProgressChanged` event. This handler would then raise the `ProgressChanged` event on the first worker, propagating the news.

For example:

```
private void ComplianceWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    var CCC = new ComplianceControlCenter(/* ... */);

    // Assume that CCC exposes a BackgroundWorker, but read below
    var worker = CCC.Worker; // "second" worker
    worker.ProgressChanged += this.PropagateProgressChanged;

    CCC.start();
}

private void PropagateProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var worker = this.worker; // "first" worker
    worker.ReportProgress(e.ProgressPercentage, e.UserState);
}
```

This code attaches an event handler to the "second" worker with

```
var worker = CCC.Worker; // "second" worker
worker.ProgressChanged += this.PropagateProgressChanged;
```

which assumes that `ComplianceControlCenter` exposes its own `BackgroundWorker` directly. Since that may not be the case, you can turn the relationship around by passing a reference to `this.PropagateProgressChanged` to the constructor instead and letting it attach the event handler for you.

Answer (score 1):

In C#, references are passed like this:

```
ComplianceControlCenter CCC = new ComplianceControlCenter(..., ComplianceWorker);
```

not like this

```
ComplianceControlCenter CCC = new ComplianceControlCenter(..., &ComplianceWorker);
```

---

As a side note, it's customary to let variables and fields start with a lowercase letter, so I'd rename `ComplianceWorker` to `complianceWorker`. Note that this also improves syntax highlighting in StackOverflow: ;-)

```
ComplianceControlCenter ccc = new ComplianceControlCenter(..., complianceWorker);
```

Answer (score 0):

if both the background workers are the same, you will run to an infinite loop. possibly, create two different backgroundworkers. if you require some thing similar between them, create a base class/interface.

Comment: I think the OP just wants to pass a reference.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just pass the reference of your `BackgroundWorker` as a parameter to your "work" method?

EDIT:

In fact you have to do that if you want to report progress or to check the `CancellationPending` flag if you can also want to cancel your operation manually.

Comment: BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

Answer (score 0):

If you need the `BackgroundWorker` itself within the `DoWork` event simply upcast the `sender`. Maybe something like this:

```
private void ComplianceWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    var worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
    if(worker == null)
    {
        //ToDo: What should happen if MS changes the behavior??
    }

    ComplianceControlCenter CCC = new ComplianceControlCenter(taskList.CheckedItems.OfType<string>().ToList(), file_box.Text, worker);
    CCC.start();
}
```

Comment: Alternative suggestion: `var worker = (BackgroundWorker)sender;`. This will ensure that the program failes with an InvalidCastException if "MS changes the behavior".

Comment: @Heinzi: Yes, you're right, but i just wanted to really point on this issue in the code example.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by doing this..

```
ComplianceControlCenter CCC = new ComplianceControlCenter(taskList.CheckedItems.OfType<string>().ToList(), file_box.Text,ref complianceWorker);
```

With this as the constructor.

```
public ComplianceControlCenter(List<string> task_list, String exe_location, ref BackgroundWorker complianceWorker)
```